# Curl timeout in php with curl soap xml call

Tags: php, xml, curl, soap, wsdl

Ok, I'm tearing my hair out on this one. I've not worked with a PHP WDSL SOAP CURL XML call at all (all of them individually but not together!) and struggling to get a response or a meaningful error.

To highlight it, I have a demo WDSL endpoint (http://office.keystonesupport.net:8084/DemoSoap/KSDSoap/KhaosKSD.exe/wsdl/IKosWeb?wsdl) that, if you stick in a browser, will respond with an XML detailing everything.

I then tried writing the PHP to access one specific operation 'GetVersion' that takes no input parameters

Posting using Wizdler (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/wizdler/oebpmncolmhiapingjaagmapififiakb), it shows that with the request headers

```
SOAPAction: "urn:IKosWebIntf-IKosWeb#GetVersion"
Content-Type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
```

and the body

```
<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <GetVersion xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>
```

I get the response

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
        <SOAP-ENV:Body SOAP-ENV:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:NS1="urn:IKosWebIntf-IKosWeb">
            <NS1:GetVersionResponse>
                <return xsi:type="xsd:string">8.149.29</return>
            </NS1:GetVersionResponse>
        </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So I put this into my script, below.
But it just gives the curl timeout error?

```
$xml='<Envelope xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <GetVersion xmlns="http://tempuri.org/"/>
        </Body>
    </Envelope>';
 $url='http://office.keystonesupport.net:8084/DemoSoap/KSDSoap/KhaosKSD.exe/wsdl/IKosWeb?wsdl';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
            "SOAPAction:  \"urn:IKosWebIntf-IKosWeb#GetVersion"",
        );
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            $url );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     $xml);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     $headers);


    print_r ($headers);
    echo '<br>';
    echo htmlentities($xml);
    echo '<br>';
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if($response === false) {
            $err = 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            print $err;
        }else{
    curl_close($ch);
    var_dump($response);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to by a syntax error on line

```
 "SOAPAction:  \"urn:IKosWebIntf-IKosWeb#GetVersion"",
```

It should be

```
 "SOAPAction:  \"urn:IKosWebIntf-IKosWeb#GetVersion\"",
```

After fixing this, the code was working for me.

**LE:** In the end it turns out that the problem was the port 8084 was filter/blocked by ISP. So, "Connection time out" was because of this.

Comment: What response do you get back? I made that change but just get 'Curl error: Failed to connect to office.keystonesupport.net port 8084: Connection timed out'

Comment: It is quite long, stack overflow complains "too long by 54059 characters". Starts with:
Array
(
    [0] => Content-type: text/xml;charset="utf-8"
    [1] => SOAPAction:  "urn:IKosWebIntf-IKosWeb#GetVersion"
)
<br>&lt;Envelope xmlns=&quot;http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/&quot;&gt;
        &lt;Body&gt;
            &lt;GetVersion xmlns=&quot;http://tempuri.org/&quot;/&gt;
        &lt;/Body&gt;
    &lt;/Envelope&gt;<br>string(54275) "<?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: I assume that there is a problem with port 8084, probable it is blocked on some router/proxy.
Try from command line **telnet office.keystonesupport.net 8084** , if it works you will see at the end the message _Escape character is '^]'._ . If it dosn't work (port blocked), last line will be _telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Resource temporarily unavailable_

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Marcel Preda, they narrowed it down for me. Turns out the code was fine (apart from the one syntax error) but it was a blocked port from my service provider.